# How to show my TreeItem hierarchy [JavaFX]

Tags: java, javafx, hierarchy

I have one question on how to show my treeView Hierarchy... for an example i have something like this....

- root

  - parent1

    - parent1.1

      - child1
      - child2
  - parent2

    - parente2.1

and If I doubleClick **child2** I want to show something like this...

root > parent1 > parent1.1 > child2

Comment: Please post code for your best attempt. Thanks.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking; do you want the entire tree to collapse to a single line on double-click? And, yes, you should post some code showing what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the hierarchy of `TreeItem` is not a difficult task. Simply traverse the tree by repeatedly going to the parent node:

```
static String createString(TreeItem<String> item) {
    List<TreeItem<String>> hierarchy = new ArrayList<>();
    while (item != null) {
        hierarchy.add(item);
        item = item.getParent();
    }

    // list iterator positioned at the end of the list
    ListIterator<TreeItem<String>> iterator = hierarchy.listIterator(hierarchy.size());

    StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(" > ");

    // join Strings in reverse order
    while (iterator.hasPrevious()) {
        sj.add(iterator.previous().getValue());
    }
    return sj.toString();
}
```

Use this to show the item when you receive the mouse event for a double click on a `TreeCell` (whatever you mean by *"showing"*).

Comment: Thanks fabian!! That's exactly what I was looking for!!